# TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I thought in python you can concat two strings, I might missing something in my little piece of code:

```
def create_set(feature, value):
  return b'{"type":"set","feature":'+feature+',"value":'+value+'}'

on = create_set("main.power", "on")
```

Comment: You *can* concat two strings; as the error tells you, you can't concat `str` and `bytes`. Why are you using `b''`?

Comment: You absolutely don't need `b''` there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: you are right that was my problem, b is a sort of a code for the reciever

Comment: And it's way better to use string formatting - https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax than concatenation.